# Holding gobj using Glist

Tags: gtk, gnome

Can gobj object be hold by Glist list.

say, I have have created GtkImage objects. Want to hold the pointer of these objects by using the list so that memory can be released thereafter its uses.

Regards,
iSight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not really clear... You can put anything you want in a GList, but it won't affect the way the memory used for your GtkImage is handled...

Comment: Over there in GList data is of gpointer type, so i am confused if object return by gobj() can be added to it.

Comment: What do you call "gobj()" ? Do you mean "pointer to an object derived from the GObject class" ?

Comment: So you can add objects to a GList, but it's only a container, it won't automatically free the data contained by the list. You'll have to free the data yourself by iterating on the elements, or call g_list_free_full. See http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-Doubly-Linked-Lists.html#g-list-free-full